# Create local network with internet access routed through a single computer

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ip-address

I want to create a local network in my workplace which has around 20 computers. All of these are connected through a single computer(server), which is attached to a router with internet access. I want all the internet traffic from my 20 computers to route through this server such that the above 20 computers are not visible from the outside network.

So the current scenario is like this:

1. The server has a IP : 172.16.16.198
2. The computers connected to this server through the router also have the IP in the same network i.e. 172.16.16.xx
3. As such all the computers in my workplace are visible from any other computer in the organisation connected to the same network.
4. You can assume that the server is connected to some internet network within the organisation, hence the private IP address(172.16.16.198)
5. All systems are Windows based.

I have tried the following so far on one of the 20 computers:

1. Changed the DNS to the server's IP.
2. Changed the default gateway to server's IP.
3. Changed to static IP of 172.16.17.12(random but having the same subnet as the gateway)

The above approach didn't work. What can I do to meet my requirement?

PS: I am a newbie to networking so this might be a very fundamental mistake.

Comment: So your server has just one network card?

Comment: No I believe it has 4 network cards. @AndriyBerestovskyy

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvotes.

Comment: The reason for downvotes is because the question is off-topic :(

Comment: Yeah I just went through the rules for posting questions. Violates point 6. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first server NIC should be connected to the router and have an IP from the same network as the router:

   ```
   172.16.16.198/24
   ```
2. The second server NIC should be connected to other computers with a switch and have an IP from the another private network, for example:

   ```
   10.0.0.1/24
   ```

   Choose proper gateway(in my case the first address worked i.e. xx.xx.xx.1) and the DNS can be set to the default DNS of first NIC.
3. Check if after those steps the internet works on server.
4. Share the server internet connection with other computers. Right click on the first NIC, Properties menu item, Share tab and check "Allow other users to use this connection". Select the name of network card with which internet has to be shared in drop down(eg NIC2). Click on Settings below to select all the services(eg. https,ftp,etc.) you want to share with the other network card.

Comment: So for the second server NIC I chose 192.168.137.xx network. I had to add the default gateway to 192.168.137.1 to point it to the router. Also added the DNS servers from the first server NIC. Also while sharing network from first NIC had to mention the name of second NIC and then go to settings button below and select all the services to be shared.
Other than that this method worked great. Add the above to the answer and I'll mark it correct :)